# Specific case of Timeline chart

Tags: charts, highcharts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am trying to create a timeline chart which is supposed to be represented like a horizontal bar chart where the horizontal bars may not have the same starting point. So it might look like this-:

```
                           ----------
                                            --------------------
```

### ---------

```
     -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

### ----------------------

```
                        ---------------------
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can use.

I have already looked into HighCharts and Google Chart with no luck.

Comment: You are looking for a "column range" chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Comment: interesting. Is it also possible to provide different colors to the bars using that column range chart?

Comment: Yes, http://jsfiddle.net/bfenp/

Comment: You could hack it together with Google Chart by using a stacked bar chart where the first series is displayed with color 'none' and is used to position the start of the second series.  In your example, you only show one value per row, so perhaps a Gantt chart would be overkill.

Comment: @dlaliberte can u give me an example of how to achieve this using google charts?

Comment: @bootkick - Looks like you worked it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623617/gannt-chart-formed-by-google-bar-chart-different-color-to-each-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take look at gantt demo chart

http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Gantt chart. Depending on what software you are using or what medium you are need it for there are a variety of options. Microsoft Project is particularly designed for it. If you are coding it into a program you will need a third-party app (something like [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/dashboard/features/dvcontrols/chart/)).